# How do I list all shell variables in IEx?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I can't figure out how to view my current context in IEx.  I want to see a list of all the variable that have been defined in the shell.  Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the current variables and their values with `binding()`

e.g.

```
iex(1)> a = 2
2
iex(2)> b = %{c: 3}
%{c: 3}
iex(3)> binding()
[a: 2, b: %{c: 3}]
```

See `h binding` in IEx for more info.

Comment: And something like `Enum.map(binding(), fn {k, _v} -> k end)` or `Keyword.keys(binding())` will get you just the variables names (as atoms).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `binding/0`, you can also use `__ENV__.vars`.

More info:

- [Macro.Env — Elixir v1.9.2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.Env.html)